# Is there an example of a minimal uncountable well ordered set I can look at and understand its "strange property"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I am studying Lemma 10.2 in Munkres' Topology and I think I understand the proof but there is something I clearly don't understand about minimal uncountable well-ordered set:

Let A be a minimal uncountable well-ordered set. Here $A$ = $S_\Omega$ $\cup$ $\Omega$. From my understanding of the Lemma and the paragraph that follows it, $S_\Omega$ is uncountable but $S_t$ (where $t<\Omega$) is countable. What makes having this element $\Omega$ make the section of $A$ by $\Omega$ uncountable where as every other section is countable? It seems like, in naive tongue, $\Omega$ destroys the "countability" of A somehow - had I defined my $A$ without this $\Omega$, then every section of $A$ would have been countable.

(1) Hence, my question - is there an example I can look at and understand this?

**Addendum:**

(2) Does it mean that an uncountable set can have subsets that are countable?

Comment: Why is this strange? It just means $S_{\Omega}$ has most of its elements in its tail -- that is, between any $t$ and $\Omega$. Consider sections of $\mathbb N\cup\{\omega\}$;  the section $S_t$ is finite for all $t<\omega$, but $S_{\omega}$ is infinite. You probably don't find that strange, do you?

Comment: I think the issue I am having with is countable vs uncountable, not finite vs infinite. By the way, how is your $\omega$ defined? I thought $S_\omega$ is countably infinite.

Comment: Yes, I was just making an analog with finite/countably infinite to demonstrate that the nature of the sections can change at a point.

Comment: MPW's comment is the right starting point: just as in $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\omega\}$ the fact that the "final point" $\omega$ has an infinite section doesn't affect the fact that all other sections are finite, so too in $A$ the fact that the "final point" $\Omega$ has an uncountable section doesn't affect the fact that all other sections are countable.

Comment: Aah, I see. Is there an example like this for minimal well-ordered set, then? Also, how is this $\omega$ defined?

Comment: "Does it mean that an uncountable set can have subsets that are countable?" The integers are a subset of the reals. More generally, any set has subsets of all sizes less than or equal to its size... that's what it means for a size to be less than or equal to.

Comment: The minimal well-ordered set is the empty set. $\omega$ is the least infinite ordinal. It is the set of all finite ordinals (i.e. natural numbers) with their usual order. The next ordinal is $\omega+1$ which is $\omega\cup\{\omega\}$ where $\omega$ is taken to be greater than all the finite ordinals.

Answer (score 1):

A set of a certain cardinality has subsets of all smaller cardinality, so in particular an uncountable set has countable subsets (many of them in fact).

If we give an uncountable subset like $\Bbb R$ a well-order (which we can do, using AC, the Axiom of Choice/Zorn's Lemma or an equivalent formulation), we get an order $<_w$ on $\Bbb R$ (totally different from the usual order on $\Bbb R$, probably) and we can consider the size of sections of $<w$: Recall that the section of $x$ is defined as $S_x= \{y\in \Bbb R\mid y <_w x\}$; $S_x$ is empty if $x$ is the minimum $m$ of $<_w$ (which exists) and size $1$ if $x$ is the successor of that minumum (i.e. the minimum of all $x$ that are $>m$, which also exists etc.):

*Either* all sections of all $x$ are countable and we can use $(\Bbb R,<_w)$ as $\Omega$ (in Munkres' notation) *or* $\{x\mid S_x \text{ is uncountable }\}$ is a non-empty subset of $\Bbb R$ and so (!) has a minimal element which we can call $\Omega$. So $\Omega$ has a uncountable section, but all $x <_w \Omega$ have a *countable* section, or else this would contradict the minimality of $\Omega$.

Note that this is not at all a concrete example as no easy description of a well-order on $\Bbb R$ can exist (for all sorts of reasons related to models of set theory without AC). But maybe it heps to think about it bit more: $\Omega$ (or $\omega_1$, as is the more common denotation) "lives inside" every uncountable well-ordered set (as hard as these are to visualise; but believe in AC and they exist!)..